# How do I stop the Pairodd from killing me?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I am in the Key Cavern and am trying to kill a pair of Pairodd. Problem is, they keep killing me before I can kill them, and I would really like for that to stop.

How do I kill them?

For reference, this is the enemy I mean:

[image: Pairodd]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Zeldapedia](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Pairodd):

> Upon Link's arrival in a room, they remain stationary and do not attack until he approaches them. When he does so, the Pairodds will briefly disappear, teleporting to a different area of the room. As they reappear, they fire a projectile at Link, which can be deflected with the Shield.
>
> The trick to defeating a Pairodd is anticipating where it will reappear and being there to strike it as it reappears. If Link uses the Pegasus Boots, they can come within range of Link's sword before they ever have time to teleport out of reach; also, they may be defeated outright if Link charges at them with the Pegasus Boots while he has his sword equipped.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that they always appear at the opposite part of the room. Top left -> bottom right, for example.